# How to extract a particular data from word file using python

Tags: python, automation

Using the docx module, I am able to read the data but I am not able to find the method to find a particular word in a table.

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("E:\Automation Activity\VBP_EWA_report.docx")

       for table in doc.tables:
           for rows in table.rows:
               if rows.cells.text.startswith("kernel"):
                   print(rows.cells[0].text)
               else:
                print('not found')
                   #if '753' in rows.text and columns.text:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to know if some table has a specific word and thats it?

First of all, make sure you've installed **python-docx** library. You can install  it by type the following on your console:

```
pip install python-docx
```

Note that it's not a very simple task iterating over docx documents in python. You must define a max length for the iterator work. Anyway, the following code works fine:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("E:\Automation Activity\VBP_EWA_report.docx")
max = 30

for table in doc.tables:
    iterator = 1
    for row in table.rows:
        if iterator <= max:
            for cell in row.cells:
                if iterator <= max and 'kernel' in cell.text:
                    print(cell.text)
                else:
                    print('not found')
                iterator += 1
```

Please thumb me up if I've helped somehow =)

Greetings,

J Heron

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying me Heron :).

Comment: I want to fetch a particular value like Database Name from a table in the word document, then I created a for loop inside a table I looped into rows and inside that into a cell. I am getting an error that .text is not an attribute of cell...then how can i fetch the value of the database name?